# In Plotly 2D histogram, how can I specify a z value instead of relying on the density of my data?

Tags: plotly

Looking at https://plot.ly/javascript/2D-Histogram/ I see that they give 500 points and they plot the heatmap of the density.

But I have data like

```
(x=0-1, y=0-1, z00)
(x=0-1, y=1-2, z01)
(x=0-1, y=2-3, z02)
(x=1-2, y=0-1, z10)
(x=1-2, y=1-2, z11)
(x=1-2, y=2-3, z12)
```

and I would like to achieve what they show. How can I do it?
I have thought of duplicating my data to give Plotly what seems to him like a distribution (i.e repeat (0, 0, 1) z00 times, repeat (0, 1, 1) z01 times, etc) but it doesn't feel right

Any idea?

Note: x=0-1 means I have a bucket of points from x=0 to x=1, same for y.
So I want my square from x,y=0,0 to x,y=1,1 to have the value z00, the square above (x,y=0,1 to x,y=1,2) to have the value z01 etc)

Comment: Can you explain your data a little bit more? What is `x=0-1`? `-1`? what is `z00`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot do that directly in Plotly, i.e. you need to replicate your data.
The problem with using a histogram is your `z00` bin which needs to be adjusted for the zero values.

```js
var z = [[], []];
z[0][0] = 1;
z[0][1] = 18;
z[0][2] = 5;
z[1][0] = 25;
z[1][1] = 12;
z[1][2] = 30;

var x = [];
var y = [];

for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < z[i].length; j += 1) {
        for (var v = 0; v < z[i][j]; v += 1) {
            x.push(i + 0.001);
            y.push(j + 0.001);
        }
    }
}

var data = [
  {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: 'histogram2d',
  }
];
Plotly.newPlot('histo', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="histo"></div>
```

The alternative would be using a bubble plot with squares, but here you can specify the size only in pixels, and not relative to the axis size. In addition it looks weird for rectangles which are not squares.

```js
var z = [[], []];
z[0][0] = 1;
z[0][1] = 18;
z[0][2] = 5;
z[1][0] = 25;
z[1][1] = 12;
z[1][2] = 30;

var x = [];
var y = [];
var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < z[i].length; j += 1) {
        x.push(i);
        y.push(j);
        colors.push(z[i][j]);
    }
}
var data = [
  {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
        color: colors,
        symbol: Array(x.length).fill('square'),
        size: Array(x.length).fill(100),
        sizemode: 'diameter'
    }
  }
];

layout = {
  showlegend: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 600
};

Plotly.newPlot('bubbles', data, layout);
```

```html
<div id="bubbles"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

The third option would be to (mis)use shapes, but then you need to specify your own color scale. This solution needs the minimal amount of data replication and is fairly flexible.

```js
var z = [[], []];
z[0][0] = 1;
z[0][1] = 18;
z[0][2] = 5;
z[1][0] = 25;
z[1][1] = 12;
z[1][2] = 30;

var c_max = 30; // the max value of your array, pre-defined for brevity
var c_min = 1; // the min value of your array
var shapes = [];
var annotations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < z[i].length; j += 1) {
        shapes.push({
         type: 'rect',
   x0: i,
   y0: j,
   x1: i + 1,
   y1: j + 1,
   line: {
       width: 2
   },
   fillcolor: 'rgb(' + 255 * (z[i][j] - c_min) / (c_max - c_min) + ', 128, 128)'
     });
        annotations.push({
            x: i + 0.5,
     y: j + 0.5,
      text: z[i][j],
    showarrow: false
        });
    }
}

var trace0 = {
    x: [],
 y: [],
 text: [],
 mode: 'text',
 type: 'scatter'
};

var layout = {
    height: 700,
 width: 700,
 shapes: shapes,
 hovermode: 'closest',
 annotations: annotations,
 xaxis: {
     showgrid: false,
  zeroline: false
 },
 yaxis: {
     showgrid: false,
  zeroline: false
 }
};

Plotly.newPlot('shapes', [trace0], layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="shapes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old question, but if anyone like me stumbles on this looking for the same answer. The following code will provide the solution to OP's question. Important to note is the *histfun: 'sum'*, merely adding the z values will result in them being ignored.

```
Plotly.newPlot(‘graph’, [{
    type: ‘histogram2dcontour’,
    x: [1,1.1,1.2,1,3,3,4],
    y: [1,1.1,1.2,2,4,4,5],
    histfunc: ‘sum’,
    z: [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1]
}])
```

From the documentation:

histfunc (str (default 'count' if no arguments are provided, else 'sum')) – One of 'count', 'sum', 'avg', 'min', or 'max'.Function used to aggregate values for summarization (note: can be normalized with histnorm). The arguments to this function are the values of y`(`x) if orientation is 'v'`(‘h’`).